# Strange behaviour with Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my app I have 2 screens that have maps on. `ScreenA` has `MapA` and `ScreenB` has `MapB`.

When I show `ScreenA`, `MapA` show perfectly and I can use it accordingly. But when I push `ScreenB`, `MapB` has an **overlay** of `MapA` that was on the previous screen. This appears to just be an image and the user cannot interact with it.

`MapA` and `MapB` are separate instances of the `Map` class.

[image]

Comment: how u have constructed your layout designs?

Comment: @Brendon both controls simply sit in a StackLayout on each page

Comment: so you trying to say here that you have snapshot of MAP A on MAP B ? is it added any way in the MAP or you just put on top of MAP as image? if you want to interact with the image try to disable the touch of MAP B or override and see how it goes.

Comment: @NikunjSakhrelia I am not doing anything besides displaying the maps. It seems to be adding the snapshot itself. I am not sure. I dont want the image there at all.

Comment: What is the image showing? Is this what you are trying to get, or what you get? And what are you trying to achieve? The fact that you did not get an answer earlier is more likely due to the lack of information in your question rather than the difficulty of the task. Put some efforts in your question if you want anyone to answer it. Regards.

Comment: @ThibaultD. moving past the condescension, the image shown is what is happening and I do not want the images to overlay like that. I simply want the map to show normally.

Comment: I faced the same problem earlier but before answering I just want to confirm that are your ScreenA and ScreenB are fragments?

Comment: @GaganSingh No, this is Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Sorry @DavidPilkington I read a little fast and thought you were trying to put both maps on the same screen. There's always been issues with moving MapViews on Android. I can't get my hand on the issue on Google's issue tracker but a similar issue has been a long story of fixed/not fixed/may be fixed on some devices. So if I were you I would look for answers on the Android side rather than on the Xamarin side.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the NavigationPage, or how you are pushing the ContentPages, debug at the first line of code of Page B and see if the Page is being rendered, you can also play with removing the navigations pages.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17407/navigationpage-remove-a-page-from-the-back-stack

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the page from the backstack is not an option for me, it needs to be there.

Answer (score 0):

**Make `MapA` invisible when in background to avoid the overlay from showing.**

Just before moving out of `ScreenA` make `MapA` invisible/transparent, probably using `setAlpha(0)` in `onPause()`

Later, when you return back from `ScreenB` to `ScreenA` make it visible/opaque again using `setAlpha(1)` in `onResume()`

If `setAlpha()` is not available for Maps just use an alternate way to make it invisible. (Havent used Maps so much hence not sure if the method is available for an instance of `Map`)

I agree this is more like a hack than a fix, but should help resolve the overlay problem.

Comment: This is one of the first things that I tried. Also, your code seems to imply that you think is native Android. It is Xamarin.Forms